# Using form_for with relational models

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, models, form-for, relational

I'm new to Rails and I have used the form_for to create/edit new users. Now I want to provide more customisation for each user and for that I have a new table that is set in a relationship to the users table.

My User model is:

```
    class User < ActiveRecord::Base
        has_many :links, dependent: :destroy
....
```

And my Link model:

```
class Link < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
    default_scope -> { order(order: :asc) }
    validates :user_id, presence: true
    validates :url, presence: true, length: { maximum: 140 }
    validates :title, presence: true, length: { maximum: 15 }
    ...
```

It's the User controller that handles the editing link (the RESTful route to edit is used to edit the users particular information so I set new ones for the link part - it will have other parts in the future as well):

Routes:

```
get 'users/editprofile/:id' => 'users#customise', as: :customise
get 'users/editprofile/:id/links' => 'users#links'
```

And the controller:

```
def links
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @links = @user.links
    if !current_user?(@user)
        redirect_to @user
    end
end
```

The migration file:

```
class CreateLinks < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :links do |t|
      t.string :url
      t.string :title
      t.boolean :icon
      t.string :icon_path
      t.integer :order
      t.references :user, index: true

      t.timestamps null: false
    end
    add_index :links, :user_id
  end
end
```

And then on my view I have a form_for:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 dispinline">
        <% @user.links.each do |l| %>
        <%= form_for(l) do |f| %>
            <%= render 'shared/error_messages' %>

            <%= f.label :order %>
            <%= f.text_field :order, class: 'form-control' %>

            <%= f.label :title %>
            <%= f.text_field :title, class: 'form-control' %>

            <%= f.label :url %>
            <%= f.email_field :url, class: 'form-control' %>

            <%= f.label :icon %>
            <%= f.text_field :icon, class: 'form-control' %>

            <%= f.submit "Save changes", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
        <% end %>
        <% end %>
    </div>
</div>
```

When I run I get this:

```
undefined method `link_path' for #<#<Class:0x007f819aa960a0>:0x007f81969f1720>
```

I know that the tables are well set because I can get the data from that using simply:

```
<% if @user.links.any? %>
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-xs-height links-change">
                <% @user.links.each do |t| %>
                    <p><b><%= t.order %> - Title:</b> <%= t.title %> | <b>URL:</b> <%= t.url %> | <b>Icon:</b> 
<% if t.icon %><%= image_tag(t.icon_path, alt: t.title, size: "30x30") %>
<% else %>No icon set<% end %></p>              
<% end %>

                <div>
                    <p>Active links: <%= @user.link %> | Maximum links: 6</p>

                </div>
            </div>
        <% end %>
```

And this will put all the information correctly.

What I would like to have is a form that allows for editing the links that are already associated with a certain user and create a new link associated with the user or remove a link.

If this is not the correct approach should I create an independent controller for handling the link creation and use resources with that? How would I go about that?

If I use in the console:

```
User.find(1).links
```

It gives me all the correct values.